# Slicing a pattern in a large 1-d NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I have got a 1-d array where I have a pattern in the enteries. I will give an example. In the array `arr`, I have 
first 4 enteries with single digits, next 4 enteries with two digits and then the next 6 enteries with 3 digits. 
(**This single, double, triple digit thing is just to highlight the pattern. The actual array have float numbers of similar values).** The example 1-d array looks like:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129, 
                6, 5, 3, 2, 21, 82, 53, 34, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119])
```

Now, one complete pattern has total 4+4+6 = 14 enteries. This pattern (or repeating unit) is repeated several hundred thousand times so the length of my array is a multiple of 14 (14 * 2 = 28 in the example `arr` above).

**Question:**

I want to extract all the one digit enteries (first 4 numbers of one repeating unit), all the two digit enteries 
(next 4 numbers of one repeating unit), and all the three digit enteries (next 6 numbers of one repeating unit).

This way I want to have my big `arr` splitted into three 1-d arrays. So the **desired output** is

```
arr1 = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2])
arr2 = array([11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 82, 53, 34])
arr3 = array([111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119])
```

**My idea**

One way could be to simply `reshape` it into 2d array since I know the number of repetitions (=28/14 = 2 in the example `arr`) and then use indexing to get all the first chunks of 4, 4 and 6 
and then `concatenate`.

```
arr = arr.reshape(2, 14)
```

and then use slicing to get the chunks as

```
arr1 = np.concatenate(arr[:, 0:4])
arr2 = np.concatenate(arr[:, 4:8])
arr3 = np.concatenate(arr[:, 8:])
print (arr1, arr2, arr3)

# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2]),
# array([11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 82, 53, 34]),
# array([111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119]))
```

But I am interested in knowing an alternative and efficient solution using some sort of **masking** and **slicing** *without* converting first to a 2-d array.

Comment: Why don't you want  to convert your array to 2D?

Comment: @Brenlla: Nothing against converting to 2d array. As I mentioned, I was exploring alternative suggestions as answered by two people below. I will now compare times to see how they stand against converting to 2d array

Comment: On my phone so I cannot check code. But how are timings if you replace concatenate with flatten?

Comment: @Brenlla: I will check that and update it in my question soon. I will also check how `ravel` performs

Comment: If all groups had the same size, e.g.4, you could get by with reshaping and one concatenate: `np.hstack(arr.reshape(2,14)[:,:12].reshape(2,3,4))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also build the mask:

```
# if you know where your indices are, otherwise use a formula
mask = np.zeros((3, 2, 14), dtype=bool)
mask[0,:, 0:4] = True
mask[1,:, 4:8] = True
mask[2,:, 8:] = True

arr1, arr2, arr3 = (arr[m.flatten()] for m in mask)
print (arr1, arr2, arr3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a mask of the pattern as requested (and supposing that arr length is an exact multiple of the mask length):

```
mask1 = [True]*4 + [False]*10
mask2 = [False]*4 + [True]*4 + [False]*6
mask3 = [False]*8 + [True]*6
```

Then you directly get the desired arrays by doing:

```
n_masks = (len(arr) // len(mask1))
arr1 = arr[mask1 * n_masks]
arr2 = arr[mask2 * n_masks]
arr3 = arr[mask3 * n_masks]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access the indices directly

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129,
                6, 5, 3, 2, 21, 82, 53, 34, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119])

run_length = 14
repetitions = 2

indices1 = [run_length * i + j for i in range(repetitions) for j in range(4)]
arr1 = arr[indices1]

indices2 = [run_length * i + j for i in range(repetitions) for j in range(4, 8)]
arr2 = arr[indices2]

indices3 = [run_length * i + j for i in range(repetitions) for j in range(8, 14)]
arr3 = arr[indices3]

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
print(arr3)
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 3 4 6 5 3 2]
[11 12 13 14 21 82 53 34]
[111 123 132 145 176 129 121 133 139 165 186 119]
```

You could put everything in a function like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, 111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129,
                6, 5, 3, 2, 21, 82, 53, 34, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119])


def extract(arr, run_length, repetitions, pattern_lengths):
    chunks = [0] + np.cumsum(pattern_lengths).tolist()

    for start, end in zip(chunks, chunks[1:]):
        indices = [run_length * i + j for i in range(repetitions) for j in range(start, end)]
        yield arr[indices]


arr1, arr2, arr3 = list(extract(arr, 14, 2, [4, 4, 6]))

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
print(arr3)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could simply reshape into `2D` (remember reshaping creates a view and has zero memory overhead and hence virtually free on runtime) with the number of cols same as the pattern lenth (14 in the sample case). Then, `slice` out the first 4 entries for first array output, next 4 for second and 8th col onwards for the last one.

Since, we need flattened output, we can do so with `.ravel()`.

Hence -

```
In [44]: a2d = arr.reshape(-1,14) # 2d view into arr
    ...: arr1,arr2,arr3 = a2d[:,:4].ravel(),a2d[:,4:8].ravel(),a2d[:,8:].ravel()

In [45]: arr1
Out[45]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2])

In [46]: arr2
Out[46]: array([11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 82, 53, 34])

In [47]: arr3
Out[47]: array([111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129, 121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119])
```

Now, say we are okay with 2D array outputs, then -

```
In [48]: arr1,arr2,arr3 = a2d[:,:4],a2d[:,4:8],a2d[:,8:]

In [49]: arr1
Out[49]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [6, 5, 3, 2]])

In [50]: arr2
Out[50]: 
array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 82, 53, 34]])

In [51]: arr3
Out[51]: 
array([[111, 123, 132, 145, 176, 129],
       [121, 133, 139, 165, 186, 119]])
```

So, why take this? Because it's a view into the original input `arr` and hence as mentioned earlier has zero memory overhead and virtually free -

```
In [52]: np.shares_memory(arr,arr1)
Out[52]: True
```

and so on for other two arrays.